# Search for quotation marks doesn't work in Sublime

Tags: search, replace, sublimetext2, sublimetext

How do I search for quotation marks in sublime?

I need to replace "file.jsp"/> with "file.jsp"> in more than 100 files

Is this possible to do in sublime using replace tool ?

I already tried backslash and it doesn't work. Any other solutions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the option `whole word (Alt + W)` in the replace toolbar is turned **OFF**